# How do I add the page break symbol in a txt file generated from my js code?

Tags: javascript

This is my code to extract data from my `html` table and print them in a `.txt` file:

```
 $('table tbody tr').each(function(){
       count+=1;
       var detail='';
       var arr1=[];
       $(this).find('td').each(function(){
            detail=$(this).text();
            arr1.push(detail);
       });
       detail='';
       for(var k=0;k<arr1.length;k++){
            detail+=arr1[k];
            detail+='     ';
       }
       userDetails+=detail+"\r\n";
       userDetails+='--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------';
       userDetails+='\n';
       if(count==40){
           //add page break symbol here
           count=1;
       }
 });
 var a = document.createElement('a');
 var file = new Blob([userDetails], {type: 'text/plain'});
 a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
 a.download = "IPAS_electric_data.txt";
 a.click();
 a.remove();
```

I want to add a page break symbol when `count=40`, so that the line printer starts printing from the next page when it gets the symbol. How do I add it?

Comment: Although there is a form feed control character, I doubt that will work in HTML when getting printed. You will probably have to wrap 40 records into an HTML element each, and then use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after

Comment: How will you be printing this?  That's the tool you need to satisfy.  You can try adding `'\f'`, which is ASCII formfeed, but as @CBroe pointed out, support is not universal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Tim Roberts and @CBroe, adding the formfeed character `'\f'` worked:

```
if(count==40){
     userDetails+='\f';
     count=1;
}
```